# Trying to toggle the class to visible / hidden but text reappears, don't see any console error

Tags: jquery, html, toggleclass

I'm trying to have a link to hide the buttons.
They disappear but reappear immediately.

Once they can stay diappeared I'll write more code for showing hiding "show me" for the show/hide link.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#small-text').hover (function() { $('body').removeClass().addClass('small-text'); })
    $('#large-text').hover (function() { $('body').removeClass().addClass('large-text'); })
    $('#button-selector').click (function() { $('#buttons').toggleClass('hidden'); })
  });

</script>
<style>
  ul {background:yellow}
  li {background:green}
  .small-text {font-size: small}
  .large-text {font-size: large}
  #buttons.hidden {display: none}
  #buttons.shown {display: normal}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>AAA-22222</li>
    <li>BBB-33333</li>
    <li>CCC-44444</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="buutton_toggle"><a href="" id="button-selector">hide buttons</a></div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="small-text">Small</button>
    <button id="large-text">Large</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Personal homework (learning js / js)

Comment: You're closing two </head>... why?

Answer (score 3):

The page is probably reloading, as that's an `<a>` element with an empty href, try preventing the default action, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#small-text').hover (function() { $('body').removeClass().addClass('small-text'); });
    $('#large-text').hover (function() { $('body').removeClass().addClass('large-text'); });
    $('#button-selector').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $('#buttons').toggleClass('hidden'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe it's good practice not to have empty href's so you should do what Leniel suggests, add a hashsign to the href. You should still prevent the default action like my answer above to not cause scrolling issues, just add the hash to href as not to leave it empty. Also jQuery has a `toggle()` function that will toggle visibility for you by just doing `$('#buttons').toggle();` without needing classes, if visiblity is all you are toggling

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a quick fix like this:

```
<a href="#" id="button-selector">hide buttons</a>
```

Note the `"#"` inside the href part...

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/YpSKu/1/